# adding animation to cluster marker?

Tags: android, google-maps, animation, markerclusterer

simple question ... how to add animation to the marker of the cluster before the cluster draw it on the map !? I kept looking but no hope. I just need to know where to start

this is how I add my cluster and how I tried to do the animation

```
private class AddMarker implements Runnable {
private MarkerOptions options;

public AddMarker(MarkerOptions options) {
    this.options = options;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    MyPoi poi = new MyPoi(options.getPosition());
    mClusterManager.addItem(poi);
    List<Marker> markers = new ArrayList<>();
    markers.addAll(mClusterManager.getMarkerCollection().getMarkers());
    if(markers.size() == 0){

    }else if (markers.size() == 1){
        animateMarker(markers.get(0),Constants.MARKER_ADD);
    }else if(markers.size() > 1){
        animateMarker(markers.get(markers.size()-1),Constants.MARKER_ADD);
    }

    mClusterManager.cluster();
    //Marker newMarker = googleMap.addMarker(options);
    //newMarker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE));
}
}
```

Comment: For `cluster marker`, you can refer to `android-maps-utils` on github [here](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils), For `animation`, refer [here](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/index.html) and [here](https://gist.github.com/broady/6314689) to get some ideas.

Comment: none of that help ... I already looked at these before... however, I got to know where the cluster markers are being animated in the `android-maps-utils` .... And for anyone who wants to know how .... all what you have to do is to build your own `DefalutClusterRenderer` just copy and past the original work from the library and do your modification "as you need" to `AnimationTask` private class ... and ta tara taaaaa

Comment: @TK52 Do you have an example for that?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

```
private void setMarkerBounce(Marker marker) {
    for (final com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker m : mClusterManager.getMarkerCollection().getMarkers()) {
        if (m.getPosition().equals(marker.getPosition())) {
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            final long startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            final long duration = 2000;
            final Interpolator interpolator = new BounceInterpolator();
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    long elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
                    float t = Math.max(1 - interpolator.getInterpolation((float) elapsed / duration), 0);
                    m.setAnchor(0.5f, 1.0f + t);

                    if (t > 0.0) {
                        handler.postDelayed(this, 16);
                    }
                }
            });
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

It's a bit ugly, but works fine. You have to pass your custom ClusterItem instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the `DefaultClusterRenderer` class, it has `onClusterRendered(Cluster<T> cluster, MarkerOptions markerOptions)` and `onClusterItemRendered(T clusterItem, Marker marker)` methods. For example, you can try the following code (in your custom cluster renderer):

```
    @Override
    protected void onClusterRendered(Cluster<ClusterItemImpl> cluster, Marker marker) {
        animateMarkerDropping(marker);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onClusterItemRendered(ClusterItemImpl clusterItem, Marker marker) {
        animateMarkerDropping(marker);
    }

    private void animateMarkerDropping(final Marker marker) {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        final long duration = 500;

        final Interpolator interpolator = new AccelerateInterpolator();

        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final long elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
                final float t = Math.max(1 -
                   interpolator.getInterpolation((float) elapsed / duration), 0);

                marker.setAnchor(0.5f, 1f + 14 * t);

                if (t > 0f) {
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 15);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Where `ClusterItemImpl` is just a class extending ClusterItem, and the `animateMarkerDropping(final Marker marker)` is slightly modified method from the answer of András.